# Morris chart - overlays in tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, charts, morris.js

I'm using Morris chart in Bootstrap tabs (each tab has charts for different periods of time).

After searching this site, I found that in order to display charts in tabs, I should use this code:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
new Morris.Line({......chart_data_goes_here
```

It works well (when code is not used, chart is displayed in 1st tab only), but when I click tabs over and over again (to switch between different charts), charts somehow "overlay". After clicking any tab for the 1st time, everything is OK, but since then, any other click makes "overlay" bigger and bigger. See examples:

[After 1st click](http://s27.postimg.org/jubys4y37/1st.png)

[After 2nd click](http://s3.postimg.org/qbwtmr4mr/2nd.png)

[After more clicks](http://s24.postimg.org/tr1eacts5/nth.png)

How can I stop this? I guess it happens because all the charts are created on 'shown.bs.tab' event at the same time and maybe the problem will go away if only one chart is created on 'shown.bs.tab' event? If so, ho can I specify which chart needs to be created after a specific ta is clicked? I'm using standard tabs:

```
<li class=""><a href="#stats-week" data-toggle="tab">weekly</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#stats-month" data-toggle="tab">month</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `shown.bs.tab` event handler simply empty the contents of the div before you load the chart, to clear out the content of the last chart that was loaded.

```
$('#yourChartDivID').empty();

new Morris.Line({...chart data});
```